# Phone call button for android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

So after some help I added a button that calls the number when clicked. The problem is, even though it works in android 4.0.3 It doesn't work in any version higher than 5 . In newer versions when you press the button the app just stops working.

```
activity_main.xml

    <Button

    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="140dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="140dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundbtn"
    android:onClick="callPolice"
    android:text="@string/btn_call"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp" />
```

and this is the java

```
    MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void callPolice(View v) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.fromParts("tel", "999", null)));

}

}
```

I didn't add the drawable and string codes because I don't think they are needed

I am new to coding so sorry if this is a basic question and let me know if you need more info about the code

Comment: I removed the unecessary `javascript` tag because there's no javascript in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it just stops working"? What happens? Do you get an error? And do you want to support Android 5.0+?

Comment: No it says "the app stopped working"and it doesnt give me any error codes and I would like the app to support android 5.0+ because I am making this app for a school project and I need to be able to run it on my phone                     Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think this code below can help you.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialContactPhone("123123123");
        }
    });
}

private void dialContactPhone(final String phoneNumber) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));
}
```

I performed some tests on devices with O and N OS and this solution works fine.

**Let me know if you have any questions about the code**

Comment: Thank you I will try it as soon as I can and let you know if it works or if I have questions. Thank You for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the intent you are using to this Intent.ActionDial, instead of Intent.ActionCall, [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) is the documentation, if you need to check the current api version of your android device you could use 
this `int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`, and make an if/else statement to complete your request

Comment: Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: I need it to be action.call not dial because it is going to be a emergency call app for a school project and it needs to be quick as possible thank you anyways I will change it to dial if I cant fix this  Thank you for the help  (I allready added the permission for action call in the manifest file)

Comment: I did try to change the code to dial and it seems to work with action dial if I can't find a way to fix the problem I will be using it.  Thanks for the help

Comment: @EmreBarış check this out to see if it helps => "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_phone_calls.htm"